# Plastic SCM FIPS error

Tags: windows-7-x64, fips, plasticscm

During configuration of Plastic SCM client - server connection on several machines I receive an error:

> This implementation is not part of the Windows Platform FIPS validated cryptographic algorithms

[image]

This is on Windows 7 enterprise SP1 64 bit

Answer (score 0):

FIPS support was added to Plastic SCM BL700 back in Oct 2015 as you can find [here](https://www.plasticscm.com/download/releasenotes/5.4.16.700)